# Consume WCF service on android - Invalid hostname

Tags: android, rest, wcf, http

I need call WCF Service in my android application. For comunication I am using OkHttp library. In desktop browser service works fine on url like this:

```
http://localhost:7915/GeoService.svc/GetRoute?source=kyjevska&target=cyrila
```

here are WCF contract::

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGeoService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method ="GET", UriTemplate = "/GetRoute?source={source_addr}&target={target_addr}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream GetRoute(string source_addr, string target_addr);
}
```

service code:

```
    public Stream GetRoute(string source_addr, string target_addr)
    {
        ...
        ...
        byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
        return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);
    }
```

and web.config: http://pastebin.com/fXDh52x4

in my solution directory I found applicationhost.config where is binding for my WCF site:

```
<sites>
    <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <site name="GeocodeWCF" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
           <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Bachelor\GeocodeAPI\GeocodeWCF" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:7915:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <site name="WcfService1" id="3">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
           <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\Bachelor\GeocodeAPI\WcfService1" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8745:localhost" />
         </bindings>
    </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

Android call by OkHttp which return **Bad Request - The request hostname is invalid**:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        encodedSourceAddress = URLDecoder.decode(params[0], "UTF-8");
        encodedTargetAddress = URLDecoder.decode(params[1], "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append(service);
    builder.append("source=" + encodedSourceAddress);
    builder.append("&target=" + encodedTargetAddress);

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(builder.toString()).build();

    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        result = response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Can you help me to fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use commande ipconfig /all and find ipv4 address of LAN adapter:
[image]

url like this works:

```
http://192.168.182.1:7915/SomeService.svc/SomeFunction?source=xxx&target=xxx
```

If still not works, try set bindings in IIS Manager, applicationhost.config, and add firewall rule for that port